# Adding Lines Automatically in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I started to learn Python and I installed Sublime Text 3. I had a problem with encoding and I solved that problem by adding the following lines

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Is it possible write these lines automatically at the opening of each file?

Comment: Do you *really* want to do that? I can see this getting real annoying real fast.

Comment: What is annoying?

Comment: I use Sublime for a lot more than Python coding, so it would be annoying to me to have every single new file contain this. But, if you're okay with that, I'm writing an answer now that will do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a very simple plugin. Select **`Tools → Developer → New Plugin…`**, delete the boilerplate content that is there, and enter the following:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class AddShebangAndCodingCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.insert(edit, 0, "#!/usr/bin/env python3\n# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-\n")


class AddShebangListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_new(self, view):
        view.run_command("add_shebang_and_coding")
```

Hit Save, which will automatically put you in your `Packages/User` directory, and save the file as `add_shebang_and_coding.py`. As soon as you do that it will be loaded. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> on macOS) to create a new file, and you should see the text at the top.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make a custom snippet
go to  **Tools > New Snippet**
copy paste this

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[

#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

]]>
    
</content>
<tabTrigger>presetName</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.python</scope>
</snippet>
```

**Save as .sublime-snippet**
now when you make new page .py type **presetName TAB**

[image: Hope it Helps]

Comment: Good solution, but this doesn't add the text automatically, as the OP requested.